# Spring LDAP + @Entry + base attribute - not working

Tags: spring, ldap, radix, odm

I have the following directory structure and am using ODM with Spring LDAP (v 2.3.1.RELEASE).

The below is the directory structure am dealing with.

```
dc=example,dc=com
dc=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com
```

I declared the base for the ldap context source in the config.xml as follows:

```
<ldap:context-source
    id="ldapContextSource"
    url="ldap://ldaphost:389"
    username="cn=ldaptestadmin,cn=Administrators,cn=config"
    password="abcxyz"
    base="dc=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com"/>

<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-
    ref="ldapContextSource"/>
```

To explain the context of the problem, here are the details:
I have two organizational units under studentBase as follows:

```
ou=groups,dc=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com
ou=people,dc=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com
```

Each entry inside the `ou=people` is as follows:

```
objectclass: inetorgperson (structural)
objectclass: organizationalPerson (structural)
objectclass: person (structural)
objectclass: top (abstract)
cn: Test Name
sn: Test
givenName: TestName
uid: test1234
userPassword: <SSHA hashed password>
```

I created a bean annotated with @Entry as follows:

```
@Entry(objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson", "person", "top" }, base = "ou=people")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Name dn; 
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now when I try create the student entry inside the LDAP like below

```
Student objStudent = new Student();
String dn = "uid=testUserName";
Name dnName = new LdapName(dn);
objStudent.setDn(dnName);
ldapTemplate.create(objStudent);
```

it is not getting created under the **ou=people** but instead  getting created in the base dn which is (**dc=studentBase,dc=example,dc=com**) as mentioned in the config.xml.

Per [Entry javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/odm/annotations/Entry.html), it says for the **base** attribute as follows : 
*The base DN of this entry. If specified, this will be prepended to all calculated distinguished names for entries of the annotated class.*

Doesn't it mean it should prepend ou=people for the @Id field of the Student??

However, in the above code, if I explicitly set the ou=person for the dn attribute, it is getting created under ou=person, no matter if I have the base attribute in @Entry or not.

```
String dn = "uid=testUserName,ou=person";
Name dnName = new LdapName(dn);
```

Am I not using the "base" attribute of @Entry annotation in the right perspective?

Or can someone explain what am getting wrong here?

Or is this used along with @DnAttribute?

Thanks.

Comment: I bet you need to check setDn() to see if it overwrites base.

Comment: I have this for the setDn in the Student class: 
public void setDn(Name dn) {
        this.dn = dn;
    }

Comment: Checked the source code but did not find a clue. In its source, getDn() does not have special treatment for 'base' though.

Comment: Check getCalculatedId(Object entry) in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/4d593dcf85deffb7d20166f41a0743be5ed4750b/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/odm/core/impl/DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue. However, I suggest this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25658026/6157415

The "@Entry base=" parameter is used by **LdapRepository** not by LdapTemplate.